# How to implement LDAP user authorization in Spring-Cloud-Dataflow server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-dataflow

please help me with this issue.

I already implemented the user authentication with

```
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      security:
        authentication:
          ldap:
            enabled: true                                                 
            url: ldap://192.168.68.241:389
            userDnPattern: cn={0},cn=Users,dc=abc,dc=com
```

After implemntic this im getting this error in From browser
[image: App Page is Not Authorized and permission was restricted]

Comment: Could you be more explicit about problem you are facing and what exactly have you tried ?

Comment: there is no such problem im just a beginer and want to know how to implement user authorization over here

Answer (score 0):

Which version SCDF is this?

It is important to note that the Data Flow security properties key prefix has `spring.cloud.dataflow.security.*` only after 1.2.x.  In 1.1.x version, the prefix starts with `dataflow.security.*.

You can refer the documentation for [1.1.x](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/configuration-security.html#configuration-security-ldap-authentication) or [1.2.x](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/configuration-security.html#configuration-security-ldap-authentication)

Comment: i am using 1.2 version

Comment: can you provide more information on what issue do you see as issue?

Comment: yes it for the user authorization. Here by default ROLE_MANAGE is populated for every page but i need to fetch the user role like a particular user have ROLE_CREATE,ROLE_VIEW how to implement it in ldap active directory and also in application.yml file

Comment: From the documentation: When configuring Ldap for authentication, you can also specify the group-role-attribute in conjunction with group-search-base and group-search-filter.

The group role attribure contains the name of the role. If not specified, the ROLE_MANAGE role is populated by default.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-security-ldap-authentication

Comment: yes i have gone through the documentation but how specify that group role attribute in application.yml is there any specific format?